# I got this error while trying to fetch data from backend Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cover_photo')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api, react-redux

I am trying to fetch my API from the backend using React and React Redux, but every attempt to do it keep failing and throwing error messages of "properties undefined" I don't really know what I am doing wrong but this has been happening for days now and I am really I need of assistance.

below are snippets of my code.

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./app/store";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import "./index.css";

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

// Import Components
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

// Import Pages
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import PropertyDetails from "./pages/PropertyDetails";
import PropertiesList from "./pages/PropertiesList";
import Property from "./components/Property";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-[1440px] mx-auto bg-white">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/property" element={<Property />} />
          <Route path="/properties" element={<PropertiesList />} />
          <Route path="/property/:id" element={<PropertyDetails />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

PropertyAPIService.js

```
 import axios from "axios";

//get properties
const getProperties = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/properties/all/"
  );
  return response.data;
};

const propertyAPIService = { getProperties };

export default propertyAPIService;
```

PropertySlice.js

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import propertyAPIService from "./propertyAPIService";

const initialState = {
  properties: [],
  property: {},
  isError: false,
  isLoading: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  message: "",
};

// get all properties
export const getProperties = createAsyncThunk(
  "properties/getAll",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      return await propertyAPIService.getProperties();
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();

      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

export const propertySlice = createSlice({
  name: "property",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getProperties.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getProperties.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.properties = action.payload.results;
      })
      .addCase(getProperties.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { reset } = propertySlice.actions;
export default propertySlice.reducer;
```

Property.Js

```
import React from "react";

// Import Icons
import { BiBed, BiBath, BiArea } from "react-icons/bi";

const Property = ({ property }) => {
  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }
  <div
    className="bg-white shadow-1 p-5 rounded-lg rounded-tl-[90px] 
    w-full max-w-[352px] mx-auto cursor-pointer hover:shadow-2xl transition"
  >
    <img className="mb-8" src={property.cover_photo} alt="" />
    <div className="mb-4 flex gap-x-2 text-sm">
      <div className="bg-green-500 rounded-full text-white px-3">
        {property.advert_type}
      </div>
      <div className="bg-violet-500 rounded-full text-white px-3">
        {property.country}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="text-lg font-semibold max-w-[260px]">
      {property.address}
    </div>
    <div className="flex gap-x-4 my-4">
      <div className="flex items-center text-gray-600 gap-1">
        <div className="text-[20px]">
          <BiBed />
        </div>
        <div>{property.bedrooms}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center text-gray-600 gap-1">
        <div className="text-[20px]">
          <BiBath />
        </div>
        <div>{property.bathrooms}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center text-gray-600 gap-1">
        <div className="text-[20px]">
          <BiArea />
        </div>
        <div>{property.plot_area}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="text-lg font-semibold text-violet-600 mb-4">
      ${numberWithCommas(Number(property.price))}
    </div>
  </div>;
};

export default Property;
```

PropertyList.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { getProperties } from "../features/properties/propertySlice";

// Import Components
import Property from "../components/Property";

// Import Icons
import { ImSpinner2 } from "react-icons/im";

const PropertiesList = () => {
  const { properties, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.properties
  );

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
      toast.error(message, { icon: "" });
    }
    dispatch(getProperties());
  }, [dispatch, isError, message]);

  // if loading is true
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <ImSpinner2 className="mx-auto animate-spin text-violet-700 text-4xl mt-[200px]" />
    );
  }

  if (properties.length < 1) {
    return (
      <div className="text-center text-3xl text-gray-400 mt-48">
        Sorry, no result found
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <section className="mb-20">
      <div className="container mx-auto">
        <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4 lg:gap-14">
          {properties.map((property) => {
            return (
              <Link to={`/property/${property.id}`} key={property.id}>
                <Property property={property} />
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default PropertiesList;
```

Comment: Can you add your "./propertyAPIService" to your question? I guess that's where the fetch is happening.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you checked that the requested data is being returned? Are you using redux devtools to check that the app state is being correctly updated with that data? Are you adding breakpoints to your component to see if that data is being retrieved from state properly?

Comment: I have used the redux devtools to cehck and all data are being populated

Comment: You are not returning jsx from Property component? Why?

Comment: @CodeThing I don't get what you mean, could you please explain, i am still new to React

Comment: @Schabbi I have added that part of the code, thank you

Comment: @MosesEyimeAkoji did you check your api endpoint separately? Is it returning (valid) data? Just use something like Postman to check your api in first place. Additionally check your system scopes: Can your React app even access the api from its location?

Comment: @Schabbi using redux dev tools, it is returning a valid date which i can even see and it same thing on my database, everything working fine except when i tried to call the children of the property